# jmeter using refcursor in callable statement [JDBC request]

Tags: oracle, jmeter, sys-refcursor

i'm not really an expert in the jmeter, i'm just learning, so i have a question:

how can i run the callable statement in the jmeter which is a stored procedure with cursor.

```
  DECLARE
  PI_TEST_ID NUMBER;
  PO_C_PAGE_RESULTS SYS_REFCURSOR;
  PO_N_ERR_CODE NUMBER;
  PO_V_ERR_DESC VARCHAR2;

BEGIN
{pk_report.pc_get_list(?,?,NULL,NULL)};
END;`
```

Then in Parameter Values section i specify following

```
1234,CURSOR,NULL,NULL
```

Parameter Types

```
IN INTEGER,OUT -10,OUT INTEGER,OUT VARCHAR
```

Variable names:

```
PI_TEST_ID,PO_C_PAGE_RESULTS,PO_N_ERR_CODE,PO_V_ERR_DESC
```

After i run this i get an error message saying:

```
Non supported SQL92 token at position: 155: pk_report
```

Please help me identify how can i run this in jmeter and get the results from the cursor
Thanks.